# Is it technically possible to render a wpf Xaml element to a direct3d texture?

Tags: wpf, xaml, directx, directx-9, direct3d9

Lets say I have a simple WPF canvas where I draw a few buttons and shapes using xaml. I would like to render the canvas to a direct3d texture so I can have access to the pixels from within the GPU.

RenderTargetBitmap allows me to do software rendering. but this will be limiting in terms of performance as I will have to manually copy the pixels to where I want.

I also looked into using a custom shader effect on the canvas. but as far as I know it is impossible to write to a separate texture using direct3d 9.

So is it at all possible? if so how?

Comment: I've not tried before but I would assume you could render your canvas or whatever as bitmap (since that's all your texture is anyway) via like `RenderTargetBitmap` and then convert that into a legitimate texture.

Comment: @ChrisW. but that would involve an expensive copy to system memory (and back, if you want to use it as a direct3d texture)

Comment: Hmm, not sure where my state of mind was a couple months ago when I made the comment but anything that's introducing bitmap pixel * will be a performance hindrance. I'd be curious the use case for wanting to turn a canvas of controls into a texture in the first place but hopefully since then you've found a remedy?

Comment: @ChrisW. I want to be able to use that texture as an ovelay for HMD (head mounted display). Another use could be incorporating WPF xaml to do simple 2D gui over an existing D3D game / app. For now I am trying to do the same using AvaloniaUI. it sort of works, but lacks the maturity of WPF.

Comment: I'm also look for a way for OBS to capture a WPF visual. Since OBS Game Capture can hook DXGI swapchain presentation, I hope there is a way to hook WPF rendering to copy the buffer/texture in the same GPU memory without going through CPU memory.